# Apache PDFBox Table/Row Alignment with Boxable

Tags: java, alignment, pdfbox, boxable

I am exporting a PDF in my program, and I wanted to create a table with ApachePDF Box which should be about 50-60% of the Page width.

However, I didnt manage to find anything about centering the rows/the table itself.

I found how to align text in the row/cell itself, but if I create a Row that does not use the full width of the page, its always left aligned, and I dont know how to center align the row, since the row or table does not have a `setAlign` method.

Im using Boxable on top of it (https://github.com/dhorions/boxable)

Comment: Pdfbox does not include an explicit table generation feature. You probably mean some library you use on top of pdfbox. Please name it.

Comment: ah yes I forgot, im Using https://github.com/dhorions/boxable

Answer (score 0):

```
  public void Test() throws IOException     {  

    //Set margins
   
    float margin = 10;

    //Initialize Document
    PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = addNewPage(doc);

    //Initialize table
    float tableWidth = page.getMediaBox().getWidth() - (2 * margin);
    float yStartNewPage = page.getMediaBox().getHeight() - (2 * margin);
    boolean drawContent = true;
    boolean drawLines = true;
    float yStart = yStartNewPage;
    float bottomMargin = 70;
    BaseTable table = new BaseTable(yStart, yStartNewPage, bottomMargin, tableWidth, margin, doc, page, drawLines,
            drawContent);

    // set default line spacing for entire table
    table.setLineSpacing(1.5f);

    Row<PDPage> row = table.createRow(10);

    // set single spacing for entire row
    row.setLineSpacing(1f);

    // my first 3x wider cell
    Cell<PDPage> cell = row.createCell((3*100/15f), "1",
            HorizontalAlignment.get("center"), VerticalAlignment.get("top"));
    cell.setFontSize(6);

            // my other 12 equal cells
    for(int i=2; i<14; i++){
        Cell<PDPage> cell2 = row.createCell((100/15f), String.valueOf(i),
                HorizontalAlignment.get("center"), VerticalAlignment.get("top"));
        cell2.setFontSize(6);
    }

    table.draw();

    //Save the document
    File file = new File("target/test.pdf");
    System.out.println("Sample file saved at : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    Files.createParentDirs(file);
    doc.save(file);
    doc.close();
}
```

Adjust set position and table width....

Answer (score 0):

Adjust set position and table width:

```
public void Test() throws IOException {
    //Set margins
    float margin = 10;

    //Initialize Document
    PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = addNewPage(doc);

    //Initialize table
    float tableWidth = page.getMediaBox().getWidth() - (2 * margin);
    float yStartNewPage = page.getMediaBox().getHeight() - (2 * margin);
    boolean drawContent = true;
    boolean drawLines = true;
    float yStart = yStartNewPage;
    float bottomMargin = 70;
    BaseTable table = new BaseTable(yStart, yStartNewPage, bottomMargin, tableWidth, margin, doc, page, drawLines, drawContent);

    // set default line spacing for entire table
    table.setLineSpacing(1.5f);

    Row<PDPage> row = table.createRow(10);

    // set single spacing for entire row
    row.setLineSpacing(1f);

    // my first 3x wider cell
    Cell<PDPage> cell = row.createCell((3*100/15f), "1",
    HorizontalAlignment.get("center"), VerticalAlignment.get("top"));
    cell.setFontSize(6);

    // my other 12 equal cells
    for(int i=2; i<14; i++){
        Cell<PDPage> cell2 = row.createCell((100/15f), String.valueOf(i),                    
        HorizontalAlignment.get("center"), VerticalAlignment.get("top"));
        cell2.setFontSize(6);
    }

    table.draw();

    //Save the document
    File file = new File("target/test.pdf");
    System.out.println("Sample file saved at : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    Files.createParentDirs(file);
    doc.save(file);
    doc.close();
}
```